# On iOS 9.2, Google Sign-In can not be presented, but pushed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin, xcode7.2

After upgrade xcode to 7.2, google sign-in controller can no longer be presented but pushed in on iOS 9.2. It's still presented on iOS 9.1 or 8. There seems to be no way to set this. Has anyone come across this?

Google sign-in version: 2.4.0

Comment: Upgraded to xcode 7.3, Google Sign-In 3.0.0, the problem persists..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going back to xcode 7.1.1 and iOS 9.1 SDK seems to solve the problem.

---

Finally I solved this, although the added code seems a bit unnecessary. Just set the modalPresentationStyle...

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use  `GIDSignInUIDelegate`?
This protocol has this method:

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  [self.currentViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I use this protocol and this works fine.(With xCode 7.2, iOS 9.2, Google SDK 2.4.0)

Comment: what if you don't use this protocol? I assume you are using this bcz you have a child VC?

Answer (score -1):

Having exactly the same issue.
The weirdest part for me, i've setup a clean project, under same conditions (Xcode 7.2.1 / iOS 9.2), and the sign-in get's presented.
Can't figure out what's happening, tried to isolate all the different components (code, configuration, etc) and i don't find the failure point that makes the sign in controller to be pushed instead of being presented.

Comment: Use comments for stuff like this.  Don't add an answer unless you have a possible answer.

Comment: @WaterNotWords i couldn't comment because i still don't have reputation for that. I believe you should checked that before down voting it

Comment: sorry about that. I'm still learning too. That said, you still shouldn't comment with an answer. Also, "me too" type  comments are not very useful unless they narrow down the problem. 'I looked everywhere and didn't find anything' is really not very helpful. I think that is why one of the first privileges (at a reputation of 15, I think) is the ability to up-vote questions. Anyway, if you do come up with a solution, be sure to edit your answer, and then the stack overflow system will allow me to vote it back up. Once again, my apologies.